# Request Failed [RpcClientException] when trying to pay with google pay TEST env

Tags: android, google-pay, android-pay

Google pay TEST env used to work, there haven't been any gpay related changes in my project for a year but now I started to get this error. This is on test environment.

I get the error when  I press on continue button (on this [screen](https://merchant.razer.com/v3/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Google-Pay-mobile-2.png))

I also get these logs:

```
2023-07-31 16:41:20.318  2792-4169  GmsTaskScheduler        com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  sendWakeUpEvent called on SchedulerClientBroadcastStrategy
2023-07-31 16:41:20.321  3284-9819  Volley                  com.google.android.gms               E  [2916] fgx.b: Unexpected response code 500 for https://payments-pa.googleapis.com/payments/apis-secure/ui2/buyflowservice/submit
2023-07-31 16:41:20.328  3284-3632  O2NetworkAction         com.google.android.gms               E  Network Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.volley.ServerError
```

[image]

What could be wrong here? How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you still face this issue?

Comment: Yes, I do indeed still face this issue

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue (and other problems) that were caused by using "NIS" as the currency code instead of "ILS". changing to "ILS" in our case fixed the problems so i would check your country and currency codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Direct Integration** then **RpcClientException** can happen if you are using one of the card from [test card suite](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/test-card-suite) provided by Google in your Android app.

You have to use the real card in your test environment to finalize your testing.

I know it is weird but they have stopped completing transaction through one of their test card suite in Direct integration.

I received this confirmation from Google support team.